# What is the correct way to perform side effects in a clojure atom swap

Tags: clojure

I'm keeping a registry of processes in an atom.

I want to start one and only one process (specifically a core.async go-loop) per `id`.

However, you're not supposed to perform side-effects in a `swap!`, so this code is no good:

```
(swap! processes-atom
       (fn [processes]
         (if (get processes id)
           processes ;; already exists, do nothing
           (assoc processes id (create-process! id)))))
```

How would I go about doing this correctly?

I have looked at `locking`, which takes an object as a monitor for the lock. I would prefer that each `id` - which are dynamic - have their own lock.

Comment: "I would prefer that each id - which are dynamic - have their own lock" - I'm not sure I understand what you mean by this. Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: @OlegTheCat I mean that a single lock for the entire atom (or volatile) is not needed. Let's imagine that creating the process takes some time. It's okay for multiple processes to be created in parallell, as long as there is a lock per ID.

Comment: If you need this kind of parallelism, first thing that comes to my mind is to have additional atom that will hold map `id -> lock`. So, firstly thread retrieves lock from this atom (or creates one and saves it; in this case function that will update atom will be side effect free) and after uses it to act on volatile with processes. Will that work?

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.

Comment: Perhaps use [add-watch](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/add-watch)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by hand with `locking`, as OlegTheCat shows, and often that is a fine approach. However, in the comments you remark that it would be nice to avoid having the whole atom locked for as long as it takes to spawn a process, and that too is possible in a surprisingly simple way: instead of having a map from pid to process, have a map from pid to *delay of process*. That way, you can add a new delay very cheaply, and only actually create the process by dereferencing the delay, outside of the call to `swap!`. Dereferencing the delay will block waiting for that particular delay, so multiple threads who need the same process will not step on each other's toes, but the atom itself will be unlocked, allowing threads who want a different process to get it.

Here is a sample implementation of that approach, along with example definitions of the other vars your question implies, to make the code runnable as-is:

```
(def process-results (atom []))
(defn create-process! [id]
  ;; pretend creating the process takes a long time
  (Thread/sleep (* 1000 (rand-int 3)))
  (future
    ;; running it takes longer, but happens on a new thread
    (Thread/sleep (* 1000 (rand-int 10)))
    (swap! process-results conj id)))

(def processes-atom (atom {}))
(defn cached-process [id]
  (-> processes-atom
      (swap! (fn [processes]
               (update processes id #(or % (delay (create-process! id))))))
      (get id)
      (deref)))
```

Of course only `cached-process` is needed if you already have the other things defined. And a sample run, to show that processes are successfully reused:

```
(defn stress-test [num-processes]
  (reset! process-results [])
  (reset! processes-atom {})
  (let [running-processes (doall (for [i (range num-processes)]
                                   (cached-process (rand-int 10))))]
    (run! deref running-processes)
    (deref process-results)))

user> (time (stress-test 40))
"Elapsed time: 18004.617869 msecs"
[1 5 2 0 9 7 8 4 3 6]
```

Comment: You could also use a `future`, which would kick off the new process immediately, rather upon first access.

Comment: @AlanThompson No, that is very wrong, because then two threads that `swap!` at the same time would start two different futures, but only one of them would end up in the process map. It's very important that we perform no side effects inside of `swap!`, which is the whole point of wrapping the call to `create-process!` in a delay; a future doesn't accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Good point. That scenario could also cause 2 delays to be created, but one would then be orphaned, never accessed, and therefore never start a 2nd process.

Comment: Right, that's the idea. A delay that never gets realized is very cheap.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you need to protect `processes-atom` from concurrent modification, so that only single thread can have access to it. `locking` will work in this case. Since, by usage of `locking`, we will manage thread safety by ourselves, we can use `volatile` instead of `atom` (`volatile` is faster, but doesn't provide any thread-safety and atomicity guaranees).

Summing up the above, something like below should work fine:

```
(def processes-volatile (volatile! {}))

(defn create-and-save-process! [id]
  (locking processes-volatile
    (vswap! processes-volatile
            (fn [processes]
              (if (get processes id)
                processes
                (assoc processes id (create-process! id)))))))
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer using a channel

```
(defn create-process! [id] {:id id})

(def ^:private processes-channel (chan))

(go (loop [processes {}]
    (let [id (<! processes-channel)
          process (if (contains? processes id)
                    (get processes id)
                    (create-process! id))]
      (>! processes-channel process)
      (recur (assoc processes id process)))))

(defn get-process-by-id
  "Public API"
  [id]
  (>!! processes-channel id)
  (<!! processes-channel))
```

Comment: This is how I do it in production code. I find the other solutions verbose, complex and hard to understand. In my production code the only substantial difference is that the go loop is called inside a function so that it isn't started when the namespace is loaded but is instead started when the init fn is called.

Answer (score 0):

Another answer is to use an `agent` to start each process.  This decouples each process from each other, and avoids the problem of possible multiple calls to the "create-process" function:

```
(defn start-proc-agent
  [state]
  (let [delay (int (* 2000 (rand)))]
    (println (format "starting %d" (:id state)))
    (Thread/sleep delay)
    (println (format "finished %d" (:id state)))
    (merge state {:delay delay :state :running} )))

(def procs-agent (atom {}))
(dotimes [i 3]
  (let [curr-agent (agent {:id i :state :unstarted})]
    (swap! procs-agent assoc i curr-agent)
    (send curr-agent start-proc-agent )))
(println "all dispatched...")
(pprint @procs-agent)

(Thread/sleep 3000)
(pprint @procs-agent)
```

When run we see:

```
starting 2
starting 1
starting 0
all dispatched...
{0 #<Agent@39d8240b: {:id 0, :state :unstarted}>,
 1 #<Agent@3a6732bc: {:id 1, :state :unstarted}>,
 2 #<Agent@7414167a: {:id 2, :state :unstarted}>}
finished 0
finished 1
finished 2
{0 #<Agent@39d8240b: {:id 0, :state :running, :delay 317}>,
 1 #<Agent@3a6732bc: {:id 1, :state :running, :delay 1635}>,
 2 #<Agent@7414167a: {:id 2, :state :running, :delay 1687}>}
```

So the global map procs-agent associates each process ID with the agent for that process. A side benefit of this approach is that you can send subsequent commands (in the form of functions) to the agent for a process and be assured they are independent (and parallel & asynchronous) to every other agent.

---

### Alternate solution

Similar to your original question, we could use a single agent (instead of an agent per process) to simply serialize the creation of each process.  Since agents are asynchronous, they don't have the possibility of re-trying the input function like `swap!`. Thus, side-effecting functions aren't a problem.  You could write it like so:

```
(defn start-proc-once-only
  [state i]
  (let [curr-proc (get state i) ]
    (if (= :running (:state curr-proc))
      (do
        (println "skipping restart of" i)
        state)
      (let [delay (int (* 2000 (rand)))]
        (println (format "starting %d" i))
        (Thread/sleep delay)
        (println (format "finished %d" i))
        (assoc state i {:delay delay :state :running})))))

(def procs (agent {}))
(dotimes [i 3]
  (println :starting i)
  (send procs start-proc-once-only i))
(dotimes [i 3]
  (println :starting i)
  (send procs start-proc-once-only i))

(println "all dispatched...")
(println :procs) (pprint @procs)
(Thread/sleep 5000)
(println :procs) (pprint @procs)
```

with result

```
:starting 0
:starting 1
:starting 2
starting 0
:starting 0
:starting 1
:starting 2
all dispatched...
:procs
{}
finished 0
starting 1
finished 1
starting 2
finished 2
skipping restart of 0
skipping restart of 1
skipping restart of 2
:procs
{0 {:delay 1970, :state :running},
 1 {:delay 189, :state :running},
 2 {:delay 1337, :state :running}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [add-watch](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/add-watch). It gets called once per change to the atom. In the watch-fn check whether a new id has been added to the atom, if so, create the process and add it to the atom. That'll trigger another call to the watch-fn, but that second call won't identify any new id needing a process.